# Groovy replaceAll inserts two sets of quotes when replacing json test

Tags: jenkins, groovy, replaceall

I have a json file with a replacement toke like so:

```
{"key": "TOKEN"}
```

Now I'd like to replace: `"TOKEN"` with `"abc"`

But when I do that, I get `""abc""` in the json file.

This is my code:

```
def replace = { String filePath, String searchStr, String replWith ->
                    def filetext = readFile file: filePath                      
                    writeFile file: filePath, text: filetext.replaceAll(searchStr, replWith)
                    filetext = readFile file: filePath
                    println(filetext)
                  } 
replace("/testing.json", "TOKEN", user.replaceAll("\"", ""))
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: `'{"key": "TOKEN"}'.replaceAll("TOKEN", '"abc"'.replaceAll("\"", ""))` returns `{"key": "abc"}` as expected. You will need to debug your code.

Comment: your code is fine. show please the value of `user` variable.

Comment: you're both right, I messed up checking in code. That's what I get for drinking and coding :)